# In an infinite sequence of tosses of a coin which turns up heads with probability $p$, a run of $N$ heads will appear a.s.

Tags: probability

Consider an infinite sequence of tosses of a coin, any one of which turns up heads with probability $p$. With probability one there will appear a run of $N$ heads sooner or later.

I don't understand the following explanation to this.

Let $S$ be the number of tosses before the first run of $N$ heads. Certainly 
$P(S>Nr)\le (1-p^N)^r$, since $Nr$ tosses may be divided into $r$ blocks of $N$ tosses, each of which is such a run with probability $p^N$. Hence $P(S=s)\le (1-p^N)^{[s/N]}$, and in particular $E(S^k)<\infty$ for all $k\ge 1$.

Here, why is $P(S>Nr)\le (1-p^N)^r$? RHS is the probability of a particular instance of having no run in $Nr$ tosses, so I thought the inequality should be reversed.

And how does this give us $P(S=s)\le (1-p^N)^{[s/N]}$?

Finally, I don't see how we get $\sum_s s^k (1-p^N)^{[s/N]}<\infty$.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Not sure what $k$ is here.  Perhaps an easier way to see the problem is to imagine that I just throw in blocks of $N$.  The probability that any given block of $N$ is all $H$ is $p^N>0$.  the probability that in $m$ attempts we never get all $H$ out of one such block is $1-\left( 1- p^N\right)^m$ and as $m$ tends to infinity this goes to $0$.

Comment: Note that, a priori, my method only gives a lower bound on the probability you want.  That is, for long finite strings my answer will be lower than what you want as I ignore the possibility that your good string straddles two blocks.  As my lower bound goes to $1$, of course, that forces the true answer to be $1$ as well.

Comment: @lulu I see that is a simpler explanation for $S$ being finite. But the original problem also asks to show that $E(S^k)<\infty$. $k$ here is a natural number. Can you see why $P(S>Nr)\le (1-p^N)^r$ here, and not $P(S>Nr)\ge (1-p^N)^r$? And how does this give $P(S=s)\le (1-p^N)^{[s/N]}$?

Comment: That  bound is the same as mine.  In order for $S$ to exceed $Nr$ we must, in particular, have failed in every block of $N$.  There are $r$ such blocks.  Clearly $P(S>Nr)$ goes down as $r$ goes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1-p^N)^r$ is the probability that if you divide the first $Nr$ tosses into $r$ blocks of length $N$, none of the blocks is all heads. Equivalently, $1-(1-p^N)^r$ is the probability that (at least) one of the blocks is all heads.

$P(S\leq Nr)$ is the probability that there are $N$ consecutive heads in the first $Nr$ tosses. One way for this to happen is if there is a block that's all heads, but there are certainly other ways it could happen (if $N>1$), so
$$P(S\leq Nr)>1-(1-p^N)^r.$$
Since $P(S>Nr)=1-P(S\leq Nr)$, rearranging gives
$$P(S>Nr)<(1-p^N)^r.$$

Also, if $Nr\leq s<N(r+1)$, $P(S>s)\leq P(S>Nr)<(1-p^N)^r$. But $r=\lfloor s/N\rfloor$. So we have
$$P(S>s)<(1-p^N)^{\lfloor s/N\rfloor}.$$

Now $P(S=s)<P(S>s-1)$ so we get essentially what you want (the exponent is $\lfloor (s-1)/N\rfloor$ rather than $\lfloor s/N\rfloor$, but that's not important).

Finally, to see that the sum $\sum_s s^k(1-p^N)^{\lfloor (s-1)/N\rfloor}$ converges, group terms with the same exponent together. For each $r$ the terms for which $\lfloor(s-1)/N\rfloor=r$ give a contribution of 
$$(Nr+1)^k(1-p^N)^r+\cdots+(Nr+N)^k(1-p^N)^r$$
and this is less than $$N(Nr+N)^k(1-p^N)^r,$$
so it's enough to check that $\sum_r N(Nr+N)^k(1-p^N)^r$ converges. This is true by the ratio test - the ratio of successive terms tends to $1-p^N
<1$.

(You had summing over $k$, but that must be a typo for $s$.)

Comment: Could you explain the last sentence a little more? I don't follow your argument that the sum $\sum_s s^k(1-p^N)^{\lfloor (s-1)/N \rfloor}$ converges.

Comment: Sure, will edit.